# import csv file and save to sql database table using VB2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, csv

Well I have read ALOT of posts and I can't quite find the perfect answer to my question, (or I have and havn't realised it!:-))

I have a large csv file that I want to read into my program and sve it to a SQL database table.

I'm useing VB2008 and my dabase is SQL2008.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers Cookster

Comment: Are you importing data as is into your database? Is there any transformation applied to your CSV file, for it to be imported?

Comment: The data is going in 'as is' with each row having 15 colums. tab delim.

Answer (score 1):

A simple & fast way would be using TSQL.

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
   FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.csv'
   WITH 
      (
         FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
         ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'
      )
```

For this to work, the CSV file should be accessible to the DB server.
Example modified per your question from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

The other option is to use [`SQLBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

EDIT: If you are OK using an external library, [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/quick_start.html) can be one of the option.

Comment: @egrunin: I am assuming that OP has a CSV file that needs to be uploaded straight into the DB, without any transform operation.

Comment: I suspect he's implementing a routine data import. In any case, this is such a common task that there really ought to be a library function to help...and there isn't.

Comment: tell me about it, I have tried alot of different things and all of them get close but the whole job. Currently I have managed to read the csv file into a dataset bound to a data grid (all the fields look good), its the next step of writing the contents of that dataset to the DB

Comment: See if SQLBulkCopy helps. The documentation on MSDN should help for you to write code to import tab separated file into your DB.

Comment: hahahah, it should but it hasnt....I think I have hit the brick wall, I'm just going round in circles....

It looks like the SQLBulkCopy should do the trick but I just can't seem to figure it out.

As mentoined I have managed to get the csv sorted and into a dataset. How do I get the dataset to be the source for the SQLBulk Copy

cheers